# Git Bash - When I try to run all tests using yarn, it doesn't show any results

Tags: windows, git-bash, yarnpkg, end-to-end

I cloned e2e project and I'm now looking to run tests in git bash. They provided me with the following command:

```
$ yarn test test/name/*
```

but it doesn't show any results (only a huge empty space appears).

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like [yarnpkg/yarn/issue 6972](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6972): "Yarn commands adds space after output and cursor disappears in Git Bash after updating to Windows 10 1809"

> Updated W10 version (actually it updated itself, but whatever) and now it's finally back to normal :)
>
> - Windows 10 Pro 64bit
> - Version 1903
> - Build 18362.295